# jQuery UI sortable prevent execution on drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using sortable widgets from the jQuery UI library and noticed something. If I sort/drop a draggable item like a div containing a script like alert('run once'). It will execute the javascript code every time it gets dropped. I understand that this pretty much makes sense since it writes it to the DOM each time. But now i'm wondering if anyone knows a way around this. The div's  (portlets) i tend to sort all contain javascript which shouldn't be run more than once :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a class to the item when it is dropped and checking for that class on subsequent drops should work. Something like:

```
$('#element').bind('onDrop', function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('dropped')) { // if the element hasn't been dropped before
        $(this).addClass('dropped'); // add the dropped class
        alert('run once');
    }
});
```